# How to make View setting changes happen simultaneously with deployment of a template

Tags: views, version-control

Making View setting changes happen simultaneously with deployment of a template. Where can I look to solve this problem?

Is there something that puts Views settings into Version Control, like Subversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a view, via the views interface or the [Features module](http://drupal.org/project/features). Both will version control the view, updating the view but chaining/updating the code (if no alterations have been made in the UI).

What I usually do, is to use a script that

- Updates the code on the
- Reverts features
- Clears cache
- Runs cron

This is done calling [drush](http://drush.ws/) commands and works very well for updating sites that doesn't rely heavily on cached data.

Comment: I ended up using Features+Subversion.  My theme was already in Subversion.  I am leaning towards installing Capistrano with Webistrano to script the deployment from the Subversion.